# Server Transfer with Session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a site contains login page and Default this is part of my code when trying to server transfer from login to Default

```
Dim userNamePlan As String = UserNameTextBox.Text
Dim PasswordPlan As String = PassWorldTextBox.Text

Dim wrapper As New Simple3Des(MyKey)
Dim userNamePlan As String = UserNameTextBox.Text
Dim PasswordPlan As String = PassWorldTextBox.Text
Dim user As String = wrapper.EncryptData(userNamePlan)
Dim pass As String = wrapper.EncryptData(PasswordPlan)

Session("un") = user.ToString
Session("pw") = PassWorldTextBox.Text
Server.Transfer("Default.aspx")
...
```

if I change Session("un") = user.ToString to UserNameTextBox.text it will transfer, if not, fail. And no Error Messages. Don't know why

Comment: Have you tried debugging the page? Isn't `user` by accident `Nothing`?

Comment: Yes I debugged the code. It appears not nothing. And no warning, errors...I use an encryption class to encrypt the data and transfer it

Comment: What do you mean "if not, fail"?

Comment: if I directly pull out the string from textbox it would works

Answer (score 0):

I hope **user** is already string..Then you can write..

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“un”)=user;
```